# Проблемы с кодировкой при редиректе

Tags: php, .htaccess, october

Добрый день. Пишу сайт на October CMS и для поиска использую готовый плагин SiteSearch. До настройки редиректов все работало хорошо. Данные поиска передавались так - [https://www.blenda.by/search-results/?q=запрос](https://www.blenda.by/search-results/?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

После настройки редиректов стало так - https://www.blenda.by/search-results/?q=%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D1%258B

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем конкретно может быть проблема.

Редиректы настроены так:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ https://www.blenda.by%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*/backend.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*[^\/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не кодировка, а представление спец символов латиницей для безопасной передачи. Попробуйте добавить NE

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.blenda.by%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)